# path to active config.properties

Tags: java, maven

In code to be refactored, to make it able to use of multiple Maven profiles, currently I've got:

```
private final static String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "config.properties";
```

Hot can I set as value a config.proprties file of currently active profile?

Comment: Or what will be best way of copying config_env1.properties to config.properties during build?

Comment: Hi Tomek :) I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but maybe you can pass the path by environment variable? It can be stored in OS or injected by build tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose second option used maven-resources-plugin for copying properties